# How to plot candlestick chart combined with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Let's consider app following :

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)

start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
# Apple stock
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
apple <- AAPL$AAPL.Close

### Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar panel
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("type",
                label = "1. Select plot type",
                choices = c("Line" = "geom_line", 
                            "Dot" = "geom_point", "Boxplot" = "geom_boxplot"),
                selected = 3
    )
  ),
  
  # Main Panel
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("sp")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sp <- renderPlot({
    colm <- as.numeric(apple)
    p <- ggplot() + aes(x = 1:length(colm), y = colm) + xlab(NULL)
    p + match.fun(input$type)()
      
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

This application plots graph with respect to chosen option. However I have no idea how to include to code option to plot candlestick chart which we can plot by code.

`>chartSeries(AAPL, type = c('candlestick'))`

[image]

However, I'm not sure how can I include it to my shiny application. Boxplot, Dot and line were logical to me because all of them were analogus. Do you know how can I add candlestick chart to it ?

Comment: Any comments about unclearity of my question will be apprecieated.

Comment: Did you want to include the candlestick chart that `quantmod` easily makes with `chartSeries` in your shiny app? Or did you want to use `ggplot` to create some kind of similar plot to the candlestick plot, but using functions from `ggplot2`?

Comment: First option - I want to add candlestick chart created by quantmod to my shiny app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to add "candlestick" as an option to your `selectInput`, and then check in `renderPlot` what your input selection is. If it's "candlestick" draw the candlestick plot; if not, use the `input$type` to guide the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)

start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
# Apple stock
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
apple <- AAPL$AAPL.Close

### Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar panel
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("type",
                label = "1. Select plot type",
                choices = c("Line" = "geom_line", 
                            "Dot" = "geom_point", 
                            "Boxplot" = "geom_boxplot",
                            "Candlestick" = "candlestick"),
                selected = 3
    )
  ),
  
  # Main Panel
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("sp")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sp <- renderPlot({
    if (input$type == "candlestick") {
      chartSeries(AAPL, type = c('candlestick'))
    } else {
      colm <- as.numeric(apple)
      p <- ggplot() + aes(x = 1:length(colm), y = colm) + xlab(NULL)
      p + match.fun(input$type)()
    }
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```